# Iterating over java List that involves Java generics <?> in Scala

Tags: scala

I have an API (from third party java library) that looks like:

```
public List<?> getByXPath(String xpathExpr)

defined on a class called DomNode
```

I try this in scala:

```
node.getByXPath(xpath).toList.foreach {node: DomElement => 

   node.insertBefore(otherNode)   

}
```

But I get compile error on node.getByXPath. 
error: "type mismatch; found : (com.html.DomElement) => Unit required: (?0) => ? where type ?0"

If I change it into:

```
node.getByXPath(xpath).toList.foreach {node => 

   node.insertBefore(otherNode)   

}
```

then the error goes away but then I get error on node.insertBefore(otherNode) 
error: "value insertBefore is not a member of ?0"

What is the answer to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to cast it.  ie,

```
node.getByXPath(xpath).toList.foreach {node => 
   node.asInstanceOf[DomElement].insertBefore(otherNode)   
}
```

You would have the same issue in Java as the type of List elements is unknown.

(I am assuming every element actually is a DomElement)

EDIT:

Daniel is right, there is a better way to do this.  For example, you can throw a much nicer exception (as compared to ClassCastException or MatchError).   Eg.

```
node.getByXPath(xpath).toList.foreach { 
    case node: DomElement => node.insertBefore(otherNode)  
    case _: => throw new Exception("Expecting a DomElement, got a " + node.getClass.getName)   
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Do this:

```
node.getByXPath(xpath).toList.foreach { 
    case node: DomElement => node.insertBefore(otherNode)   
}
```

By using `case`, you turn it into a pattern matching function. If there's any non-DomElement returned, you'll get an exception -- you can add another `case` match for the default case to handle it, if necessary.

What you *shouldn't* do is use `asInstanceOf`. That throws away any type safety for little to no gain.

Comment: That's a good point, at least with the partial function you have an an opportunity to do something if it's not a DomElement.   But if you don't provide another `case` it's basically equivalent to the cast - you'd get an exception if it's not the expected type.